# Hibernate JPA can't referenceColumn a @JoinColummn in other @Entity

Tags: java, hibernate, jpa

I've got the @Entity

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "CO_CONTRACT")
public class Contract {

   @ManyToOne
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumnsOrFormulas({@JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "TRAVELDATETYPE", referencedColumnName = "CODEVALUE")),
            @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(referencedColumnName = "GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT", value = "'TRAVELDATETYPE'"))})
    private BusinessElementValue travelDateType;

}
```

And BusinessElementValue

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENTVAL")
public class BusinessElementValue extends AuditInfo {

    @Id
    @JoinColumn(name = "GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT")
    private BusinessElement businessElement;

    @Id
    @Column(name = "CODEVALUE")
    private String codeValue;

}
```

This fails because

```
Unable to find column with logical name: GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT in GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENTVAL
        at org.hibernate.cfg.Ejb3JoinColumn.checkReferencedColumnsType(Ejb3JoinColumn.java:858)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.BinderHelper.createSyntheticPropertyReference(BinderHelper.java:243)
        at org.hibernate.cfg.ToOneFkSecondPass.doSecondPass(ToOneFkSecondPass.java:100)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processEndOfQueue(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1752)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processFkSecondPassesInOrder(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1696)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1583)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278)
        at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.build(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:83)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:418)
        at org.hibernate.boot.internal.MetadataBuilderImpl.build(MetadataBuilderImpl.java:87)
```

But if i change it in BusinessElementValue

```
@Id
@Column(name = "GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT")
private String businessElement;
```

Then it works!

Why is ot failing in the first case  ?

Can i referenceColumn a column that is a @JoinColumn in the other @Entity ? 
What am i doing wrong ?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

```
@Id
@JoinColumn(name = "GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT")
private BusinessElement businessElement;
```

needs to add referencedColumnName

```
@Id
@JoinColumn(name = "GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT", referencedColumnName="id_in_BusinessElement")
private BusinessElement businessElement;
```

There should be an id column in BusinessElement.

Answer (score 0):

you need to use relation specification like `@OneToOne`: because is the id

```
@Id
@OneToOne
@Column(name = "GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT")
private BusinessElement businessElement;
```

dont forget to delete your database before your test

Comment: Thank you for your comment , i don't saw the String value

Comment: yes, because i added @OneToOne to specify the relation between the table and  a id from other table(Entity)

Answer (score 0):

I've finally solved.

You have to create a @EmbebedId with the compisete key, then it works

```
@Embeddable

    public class BusinessElementValuePK implements Serializable {

        @ManyToOne <-- This is very important, if not it doesn't works
        @JoinColumn(name = "GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT")
        private BusinessElement businessElement;


        @Column(name = "CODEVALUE")
        private String codeValue;

    }


@Entity
@Table(name = "GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENTVAL")
public class BusinessElementValue extends AuditInfo {


    @EmbeddedId
    private BusinessElementValuePK businessElementValuePK;

}

Contract {

  @ManyToOne
    @NotFound(action = NotFoundAction.IGNORE)
    @JoinColumnsOrFormulas({@JoinColumnOrFormula(column = @JoinColumn(name = "TRAVELDATETYPE", referencedColumnName = "CODEVALUE")),
            @JoinColumnOrFormula(formula = @JoinFormula(referencedColumnName = "GD_BUSINESSCODEELEMENT", value = "'TRAVELDATETYPE'"))})
    private BusinessElementValue travelDateType;

}
```